# Scheme Racket Calculate Max Element in List Infinite Loop

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm writing my very first program in Scheme and after fighting off a bunch of syntax issues, I hit an infinite loop. I'm simply trying to retrieve the biggest number in a list and print it to the console. Here's what I have so far:

```
(define (max-num lst)
  (cond [(= 0 (length lst)) (displayln "Your list is empty!")]
    [(= 1 (length lst)) (displayln (car lst))]
      ;start comparing recursively
    [>= (car lst) cdr(car lst) (max-num (list (car lst) (car(cdr lst))))]
          (else (max-num(cdr lst))))
    )
          )
(max-num '(1 2 3 4 5))
(max-num '(-5 -3 -2 -13))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A very useful tool to debug programs is the Program Stepper.
The stepper will show you how the program is evaluated one step at a time.
The stepper only works for programs written in the teaching languages, so I have changed your program a little (I haven't changed the logic).

In DrRacket open a new file. Paste the program below (including the examples at the end). Choose the "Choose language..." item in the "Language" menu. Then choose the "Beginner" language.
Finally click the "Step" button (next to the icon with a checkmark+looking glass).

```
(define (max-num lst)
  (cond
    [(= 0 (length lst))              "Your list is empty!"]
    [(= 1 (length lst))              (car lst)]
    [(>= (car lst) (cdr (car lst)))  (max-num (list (car lst) (car(cdr lst))))]
    [else                            (max-num(cdr lst))]))

(max-num (list 1 2 3 4 5))
(max-num (list -5 -3 -2 -13))
```

Click your way through the evaluation until you spot the error.

Comment: Wow thank you! I had no idea about this. So I began stepping through the code, and I hit an issue where it was "expecting a pair" for >= operation, but only given one. How come? I have two expressions. Is it a parenthesis issue?

Comment: Never mind, I got it! I had to switch the cdr and car around for the second argument. Thank you so much for the "Beginner" language! It helped a ton!

Comment: yay stepper! Thanks Jens.

Comment: Why don't we have a stepper for `#!racket`?

Comment: @JohnClements That question is for you (see above).

Comment: Yes, you're right. Short version: the hard work involved in the stepper is unwinding all of the macros; as you can tell if you take a look at the macro stepper, the fully unwound source is pretty horrible; you wouldn't want to step through that. Also, there are some tricky issues surrounding mutation. I ... I guess I wouldn't hold my breath.

Answer (score 2):

`>= (car lst) cdr(car lst)` should be in parentheses like `[(>= (car lst) cdr(car lst)) (max-num (list (car lst) (car(cdr lst))))]`

Comment: Thank you for the help! These parenthesis are going to be the death of me...  Now it doesn't like my >= expression evaluation, but that's a different issue I guess.